# Why do definitions use 'que' rather than 'lo que'

Tags: definiciones, clíticos

For example:

> lector - que lee

Why not:

> lector - lo que lee

Comment: "lo que lee" would be "the thing that is read"(which may be a book) and doesn't mean the person who reads. Maybe you mean "el que lee".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's an adjective. It's not a person or thing; it's the quality of being reading at the moment or having the habit of reading, which you can apply to things o people, as in, I don't know, "el topo lector" (= "el topo que lee").

This is how adjectives are defined. You can't say that *rojo*, for example, means "lo de color encarnado", because you would be defining an adjective in terms of a noun. So you say "rojo" means "de color encarnado". The (sub?) phrases "de color encarnado" and "que lee" have adjectival functions.

Now, it's true that "lector" is often used as a noun. If you regard it as such, "el que lee" is an adequate definition.